# Firestore firebase admin listCollections get by field value

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have `subcollections` with unknown names,  I can list them with `listCollections` from `Node.js` admin sdk. however, I want to list those subcollections based on the field value within that subcollection

`root_collecton->docid1->subcollection_eiruj2929383ssk->doc->fieldvalue(timestamp)`

`subcollection_eiruj2929383ssk` subcollection with unknown name

sort the `subcollection` based on the `fieldvalue`

Will it be possible? I am free to change the design, if any other suggestion please suggest.

Eg: Restaurants are the `subcollection` with unknown names, it has `documents` like menuitems, reviews, customer.

I want to list all unknown named restaurants sort by timestamp, a fieldvalue in customer document. so i want the restaurants to be ordered by the most recent customer check in.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to filter the results from listCollections.

In general, it's not a good idea to have collections or subcollections with unknown names.  That works against good data modeling, and the way that Firestore was intended to be used.  Any variable values that require filtering need to be in document field values.  Consider instead making a restaurant a document and its menu items a subcollection nested under that document with a known name.